# MariaDB UUID datatype not orders correctly

Tags: mariadb, uuid

I'm using MariaDB 10.8.3. I have a table with a PK of type UUID. I'm inserting ordered UUIDs generated in application side. When I retrive the data of the table ordering by UUID column, it is not ordered as expected. For example:

```
SELECT id_label, date_add FROM mod_label ORDER BY id_label ASC;
```

The retrieved data is this:

[image]

But if I cast the UUID to char or convert to hex, the result is ordered as expected:

```
SELECT id_label, date_add FROM mod_label ORDER BY CAST(id_label AS CHAR(36)) ASC;
SELECT id_label, date_add FROM mod_label ORDER BY HEX(id_label) ASC;
```

[image]

As I understand it, MariaDB saves UUIDs as 128-bit integers, so I don't understand this behavior.

Can someone explain me this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: UUIDs (and other hash-like ids) are not intended for display.  Whyever would you want what you are asking for?  My question is serious.  If you have a good use case for getting that ordering (and thanks for the two workarounds), then maybe the documentation should point them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because MariaDB UUID are stored in an [index friendly manner](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-26664), the order (per [code](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/commit/b9f19f7eae960b6ebf769a3d0c63045ed5f2ce6c)) is:

UUID values, `llllllll-mmmm-Vhhh-vsss-nnnnnnnnnnnn`

are stored as, `nnnnnnnnnnnn-vsss-Vhhh-mmmm-llllllll`

This provides a sorting order, if a UUIDv1 (node and timestamp) is used, of the node, followed by the timestamp.

Comment: A subtle incompatibility between MariaDB and MySQL or older versions of MariaDB?  Is it noted in the documentation?

Comment: The incompatibility within MariaDB existed only between the preview release of uuid in the 10.7 beta after that so its not documented. I hope to write up the impact of this answer and the MySQL difference in the KB for the [uuid data type](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/uuid-data-type/) today.

Comment: I haven't found a decent MySQL reference with this level of detail. Do you know one?

Comment: Well, this Question points out one incompatibility (albeit a minor one).  I'm pretty sure Oracle does not shuffle the bits the way that MariaDB does.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [uuid v7](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid), then you can convert it to mariadb-sortable format with php 8.1:

```
$uuid = Uuid::uuid7()->toString()

$sortableUuid = substr($uuid, 24, 8)
            . "-"
            . substr($uuid, 32, 4)
            . "-"
            . substr($uuid, 19, 4)
            . "-"
            . substr($uuid, 14, 4)
            . "-"
            . substr($uuid, 0, 8)
            . substr($uuid, 9, 4);
```